# What licenses are needed for ArcGIS Server and SDE (vs a FOSS setup)?

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server

Does anyone know where I could find a cost breakdown for an ESRI/Microsoft GIS server and database setup?

I'm trying to figure out all the costs associated with an ArcGIS Server/SDE sitting on top of SQL Server, and compare it to the support cost of a FOSS setup.

**From Microsoft we appear to need:**

Windows Server - cost per processor and [CAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_access_license) for each user (ArcGIS Server apparently needs IIS which is part of Windows Server)

SQL Server - cost per core and CAL for each user

**From ESRI:**

ArcGIS for Server, Server Image Extension, ArcGIS for Desktop Standard Level (Needed to edit data in SDE)

Any information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Total Cost of Microsoft and ESRI products (minus tax)

Comment: Don't forget the cost of extra hardware if using Windows, sql server, arcgis vs foss alternatives, based on for instance linux postgis and so on. Notice the "for instance" since with foss alternatives you are free to choose.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft SQL Server 2012

> ```
> Datacenter: Processor + CAL licensing model, $4,809
> **Standard: Processor + CAL licensing model, $882**
> Essentials: Server licensing model (25 user account limit), $425
> Foundation: Server licensing model (25 user account limit), OEM only (price not disclosed)
> ```

source:
http://mla.microsoft.com/default.aspx
(IE only)

With ESRI you are required to contact your local rep.

http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/pricing

If in the US you can get bundle offers (ending 28 Feb 2013)
http://www.esri.com/partners/apps/hw_promo/index.cfm?fa=search#results

Example: ArcGIS for Server Workgroup Standard 
http://www.esri.com/~/media/Files/Pdfs/partners/hardware/dellstandardworkgroup.pdf
($13,600)

Total (not including Tax or shipping/handling)

**$14,482**